# Можно ли отлавливать консоль warnings в браузере? Angular

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, typescript, angular, браузер

Нужно отлавливать ошибки и предупреждения в консоли, ошибки еще понятно более менее как. Есть ли возможность как-то глобально отлавливать варнинги не через переопределения console.warn?

Answer (score 0):

Пользовательская обработка ошибок для Angular - https://rollbar.com/blog/client-side-angular-error-handling/